# SQL how to show the page of results that includes a specific record

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an SQL database, and I use pagination and sorting to show it.

e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM People_Table
WHERE Country=@Country
ORDER BY Postcode OFFSET @Offset ROWS FETCH NEXT 12 ROWS ONLY
```

If a new person is added, I want to show the page of results which contains the new person. They might be halfway down that page, so I don't want to just find them and the next 11 records. Any ideas on how to do this elegantly?

Comment: Microsoft Azure SQL Database

Comment: won't a simple `top 1 with order  by` work.if not can you explain along with sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly what I'm thinking is you'd need to include a calculated column to contain page number that is based on an NTILE grouping that is based on the order by.  Something like this using a partition over clause with an [NTILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx).  See link for details on NTILE.

```
DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 12;
DECLARE @PageCount INT;

SELECT  @PageCount = COUNT(*) / @RowsPerPage
FROM    People_Table
WHERE   Country = @Country;

SELECT  * ,
        NTILE(@PageCount) OVER ( ORDER BY PostCode ) AS PageNum
FROM    People_Table
WHERE   Country = @Country
ORDER BY Postcode
        OFFSET @Offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY;
```

Code sample for reference only, I haven't tested it other than making sure it would parse.

**Comments:**  You'd probably need to be more specific on your order by however as ordering by postal code doesn't guarantee the order of rows that share the same postal code.  *This would be a problem when one postal code starts spanning more than one page.*  So you want to order by postal code and by person name or something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks NTILE I'll give that a go. (The postcode was me trying to give a more understandable table than the one I actually have).

Where I'd got to was:

```
SELECT RowNo 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DriverID) AS RowNo,Id
FROM DriverID_Table 
WHERE Fleet IN (SELECT Fleet_ID FROM Fleet_Table WHERE User_Id=@user)) AS t
WHERE Id=@ID
```

using the value returned from that to calculate a page number and then a second query to fetch that page,

```
page = (int)RowNo/12; Offset = page*12;

SELECT * 
FROM DriverID_Table
WHERE Fleet IN (SELECT Fleet_ID FROM Fleet_Table WHERE User_Id=@user)
ORDER BY DriverId 
OFFSET @Offset ROWS FETCH NEXT 12 ROWS ONLY
```